# Run remote command with Javascript

Tags: linux, ssh, javascript, awk

I want to run an awk command for a file in remote server. I connect with ssh and I run the following command:

```
cat /orch/servers | grep "+sNo+" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Type of this command's output is string. But I want to this output be array. The javascript code is below:

```
vmIDListCmd = "cat /orch/servers | grep "+sNo+" | awk '{print $1}'"
try {
session = new SSHSession(hostName, username, 22);
session.connectWithPasswordOrIdentity(passwordAuthentication, password);
vmIDList = session.executeCommand(vmIDListCmd, true);
} 
catch (e) {
throw "Unable to execute command: " + e;
} 
finally {
if (session) {
    session.disconnect();
}
System.log(vmIDList);
}
```

Output:

```
vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4
```

vmIDList variable (the output) is a string. I want to this variable be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string can be easily converted to an array using `split`.

```
var newArray = vmIDList.split(" ");
```

Comment: I tried this command. It's work but my array has just big 1 element? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Check that in the string `vm1` and `vm2` are separated by a space (because it is the argument used in the split), and test with this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wb1nqd0h/7/) where I take the string, convert it to array and iterate it.

Comment: Sorry. It is an array but I use a tool called by "VMWare Orchestrator" for this project and there is a bug I think so. I must think another solution for split the string.